# How Do I Force A DataSource Location In Crystal Reports?

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, connection, report, datasource

I've inherited some pretty awful code that uses Crystal Reports extensively. My issue is that I can get the reports working just fine locally, but when I move to the production server it crashes.

When I go to change the connection info in the "Set DataSource Location" wizard in visual studio, it won't let me change it to the production server's connection info because it tests the connection and naturally gets a failure. Upon that failure, it reverts back to the old "working" connection info.

I KNOW it can't connect remotely. I'm simply trying to change the connection info for when I deploy it on the server. Surely there's a way to force this info into the report.

Any help would be tremendously appreciated. I'm running out of hair to pull out.

Comment: consider tagging/mentioning the language and dbms

Answer (score 0):

You can create a ConnectionInfo object and then apply it to each of the tables on the report using `ApplyLogOnInfo`

Here's the sample from [MSDN article on the ConnectionInfo Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms226340%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

```
private void SetConnectionInfo (string table, string server, string database, string user, string password)
{ 
   TableLogOnInfo logOnInfo = new TableLogOnInfo();
   logOnInfo = Report.Database.Tables[table].LogOnInfo;
   ConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo ();
   connectionInfo = logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo;

   connectionInfo.DatabaseName = database;
   connectionInfo.ServerName = server;
   connectionInfo.Password = password;
   connectionInfo.UserID = user;
   Report.Database.Tables [table].ApplyLogOnInfo(logOnInfo);
}
```

Typically though I find it easier to just use an ODBC or TNS entry name for ORACLE and keep the name the same in all environments which avoids the code entirely.